# Get Absolute Results outside of Low Search Results tag pair

Tags: low-search

Is there any way to get the **absolute results** on a Low Search results page outside of the {exp:low_search:results} tag pair?

Something like:

```
{exp:low_search:absolute_results query="" collection="" limit=""}
```

So I can do this without the tag pair extra coding:

```
<a href="#venues">
    Show all {exp:low_search:absolute_results query="{segment_2}" collection="venues"} Venues found
</a>
```

Using the tag pair once or twice on a page is fine but it starts to get unwieldy after a while because I am grouping the collections on Bootstrap tabs and other UI foolery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the moment.

When Low Search filters entries, it will pass on its search results (the the form of entry IDs) to the native channel:entries tag. This, in turn, will filter down the entries even further depending on things like status, future/expired entries and other native parameters.

EE currently does not offer an API for firing those filters and returning just a results number -- this is only available when calling the channel:entries tag with the absolute_results var.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you are doing on the page, you could of course simply save the results of the tag-pair(s) when you first run them and then get those back later in the page.  There are several ways to do this, including [stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki) and [CE Variables](http://docs.causingeffect.com/expressionengine/ce-variables/user-guide/variables.html) (both of which are free).